# Array elements in numbered list not working JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, list

Can someone please help me figure out why my code isn't printing out the elements in the array (AtomNames) in a numbered list. Here is my type script code

```
// Find the placeholder node in the HTML document
const div1 = document.getElementById("part1");

// Create a new H2 and its text
const h1: HTMLHeadingElement = document.createElement("h2");
const h1text: Text = document.createTextNode("Part 1");
h1.appendChild(h1text);
div1?.appendChild(h1);

// Create a new LI and its text
var node = document.createElement("LI");  
var list =  '<ul> <li>' + atomNames.join("</li><li>") + '</li> </ul>';
const part1list = document.createTextNode(list);

node.appendChild(part1list);
div1?.appendChild(node);
```

Here is my HTML code. Please help! thanks

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="./part0.ts" defer> </script>
    <script src="./nunezjo.ts" defer> </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/mocha/mocha.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
    <div id="part0" class="result"></div>

    <div id="part1" class="result"></div>


    <div id="part2" class="result"></div>
    <div id="part3" class="result"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/chai/chai.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/chai-dom/chai-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
    <script class="mocha-init">
      mocha.setup("bdd");
      mocha.checkLeaks();
    </script>
    <script src="./mocha-checker.ts"></script>
    <script class="mocha-exec">
      mocha.run();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: This is what my code is outputting]

Comment: You’re creating text nodes so the content will be parsed as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why my code isn't printing out the elements in the array (AtomNames)
> in a numbered list

Because you're using ul (unordered list) instead of ol (ordered list/numbered list)

Also you're creating text nodes in this point `document.createTextNode(list)`

Use this code:

```js
const atomNames = ["a", "b", "c"];
const div1 = document.getElementById("part1");
const ul = document.createElement("ol");
let li, text;

for (let i = 0; i < atomNames.length; i++){
  li = document.createElement("li");
  text = document.createTextNode(atomNames[i]);
  li.appendChild(text);
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
div1.appendChild(ul);
```

```html
   
    <div id="part1" class="result"></div>
```